# How display duplicate attribute error validation message in yii

Tags: yii, cactiverecord, yii-cformmodel

I need display error message when user register end he input email which exist.I try this in my view:

```
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model, NULL, NULL, array("class" => "standard-error-summary")); ?>
```

and this

```
if($model->hasErrors())
  echo CHtml::errorSummary($model);
```

But it doesn't work.

There is my rules method of User model

```
    public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('status', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('first_name, last_name, email, password', 'length', 'max'=>255),
        array('email', 'unique', 'className' => 'User', 'attributeName' => 'email', 'message'=>'This Email is already in use'),
        array('id, status, first_name, last_name, email, password', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

RegistrationForm Model:

```
    public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('first_name, repeat_password, last_name, password,email', 'required'),
        array('email', 'email'),
        array('password', 'compare','compareAttribute'=>'repeat_password'),
      );
  }
```

and my register action:

```
    public function actionRegister()
{
    $model = new RegistrationForm;
    if(isset($_POST['RegistrationForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['RegistrationForm'];
        if($model->validate())
        {
          $user = new User;
            $user->first_name = $model->first_name;
            $user->last_name = $model->last_name;
            $user->password = $model ->password;
            $user->email = $model->email;
            $user->save();
        }
    }
    $this->render('register',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Such as you validate `RegistrationForm` model, you must have `unique` rule in it (not onlu in `User` model). So you can add this rule in your `RegistrationForm` model too:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('first_name, repeat_password, last_name, password,email', 'required'),
        array('email', 'email'),
        // THIS RULE CHECKS EMAIL UNIQUE IN RegistrationForm MODEL
        array('email', 'unique', 'className' => 'User', 'attributeName' => 'email', 'message'=>'This Email is already in use'),
        array('password', 'compare','compareAttribute'=>'repeat_password'),
      );
}
```

So not not necessary to add custom rule.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I added this method in my RegisterationForm Model

```
public function uniqueEmail($attribute, $params)
{
    if($user = User::model()->exists('email=:email',array('email'=>$this->email)))
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Email already exists!');
}
```

and added

```
array('email', 'uniqueEmail','message'=>'Email already exists!'),
```

to the rules method